# Can a proxy's constants be accessed from its implementation contract?

Tags: solidity, proxy-contracts, upgrading

I'm trying to understand if this is possible:

```
contract Proxy {
    constant string greeting = "hello world";

    fallback(){
        // delegates to ImplementationForProxy
    }
}
```

```
contract ImplementationForProxy {

    function sayHello(){

        // Compiler doesn't know what "greeting" is
        // but is there a different way of accessing it?

        return greeting; 
    }
}
```

---

EDIT:

For anyone who comes across this in the future, check out this library as a way of cheaply storing immutable configuration data for a proxy: https://github.com/wighawag/clones-with-immutable-args

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small nit: the correct way to declare constants is `string constant greeting` :)

Regarding the question: the short answer is no. The constants are optimized at the compile time and are stored as a part of the code. The implementation shares storage with the proxy, but they have different codes.

If you want to share a constant with a proxy, you can create a `Constants.sol` file with the following content and import it both in the file with the proxy and the implementation.

Constants.sol file:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

string constant greeting = "hello world";
```

Comment: Ah thanks! What I was hoping to do is automate an off chain service that writes custom solidity for proxies that share the same implementation,  but have gas-efficient custom configuration as constants. The config would also be dynamic in size, which makes it more complicated. If you know of a way to do that that doesn’t require writing storage, I’d love to hear it!

Comment: I think that the most gas-efficient way is to have your offchain service edit the Constans.sol file I mentioned above, but this would make the implementation different for each service.

However, since you want the implementation to be *the same* everywhere, i.e. with the same constants, the only way to do it is with storage, yes. It is not that much different from deploying a contract with different constants, since these constants go into the contract's code and are stored by every Ethereum node (though the price for code is cheaper).